# How to understand of bitmap_set()?

Tags: c, linux, algorithm, linux-kernel, bit-manipulation

In the linux kernel, include/linux/bitmap.h, the function of bitmap_set()

```
void bitmap_set(unsigned long *map, int start, int nr)
{
    unsigned long *p = map + BIT_WORD(start);   
    const int size = start + nr;
    int bits_to_set = BITS_PER_LONG - (start % BITS_PER_LONG);
    unsigned long mask_to_set = BITMAP_FIRST_WORD_MASK(start);

    while (nr - bits_to_set >= 0) {
        *p |= mask_to_set;
        nr -= bits_to_set;
        bits_to_set = BITS_PER_LONG;
        mask_to_set = ~0UL;
        p++;
    }
    if (nr) { 
        mask_to_set &= BITMAP_LAST_WORD_MASK(size);
        *p |= mask_to_set;
    }
}

#define BIT_WORD(nr)        ((nr) / BITS_PER_LONG)
#define BITS_PER_LONG __WORDSIZE
#ifndef __WORDSIZE
#define __WORDSIZE (__SIZEOF_LONG__ * 8)
#endif
#define BITMAP_FIRST_WORD_MASK(start) (~0UL << ((start) % BITS_PER_LONG))
#define BITMAP_LAST_WORD_MASK(nbits)                    \
(                                   \
    ((nbits) % BITS_PER_LONG) ?                 \
        (1UL<<((nbits) % BITS_PER_LONG))-1 : ~0UL       \
)
```

I read this function, but I still can't understand it. For examples:

1. I think it should be

   ```
   bits_to_set = start % BITS_PER_LONG;
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   bits_to_set = BITS_PER_LONG - (start % BITS_PER_LONG);
   ```
2. I think it should be `size = nr` instead of `size = start + nr;`, because `nr` represents the length of area which should set.
3. How to understand of `BITMAP_LAST_WORD_MASK(nbits)`?
4. How to understand the design of this function?

Thank you

Comment: `size` is a bit misnamed. It's the index of the last bit to set (starting from the bitmap's first bit, not from `start`). The last word mask wouldn't work with your version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since

```
int bits_to_set = BITS_PER_LONG - (start % BITS_PER_LONG);
```

thus

```
(start % BITS_PER_LONG) + bits_to_set = BITS_PER_LONG;
```

From that we can see `bits_to_set` are the missing (if any) number to complete the `start` when we divided start into equal pieces of size `BITS_PER_LONG`.

```
|0       BITS_PER_LONG,       2*BITS_PER_LONG,       3*BITS_PER_LONG,   start|
|                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                   bits_to_set
```

Then we are testing `(nr - bits_to_set)` value to find if nr is greater or equal than remainder. If not bits are within bits_to_set so last word is what we need

```
if (nr) { 
    mask_to_set &= BITMAP_LAST_WORD_MASK(size);
    *p |= mask_to_set;
}
```

else we have to go through other BITS_PER_LONG-sized pieces of map:

```
while (nr - bits_to_set >= 0) {
    *p |= mask_to_set;            // 1
    nr -= bits_to_set;            // 2
    bits_to_set = BITS_PER_LONG;  // 3
    mask_to_set = ~0UL;           // 4
    p++;                          // 5
}
```

first run:
1. apply mask
2. subtract the reminder (bits_to_set) so nr is now multiple of BITS_PER_LONG (if we divide it we know how many BITS_PER_LONG-sized chunks are there)
3. now bits_to_set = BITS_PER_LONG 5. increment pointer

next runs:
we are subtracting chunks and moving forward

Comment: Thank you, and I want to understand the design of this function?